# how to register rtsp protocol in firefox 9 so it would be played in VLC instead of Real Media

Tags: windows, firefox, vlc-media-player, rtsp

VLC is able to handle rtsp links without any other codecs installed on the system. Manually copying and pasting a link that contains rtsp with 3gp stream works fine.

But when I click the same rtsp link in Firefox I get this:

```
Firefox doesn't know how to open this address,
because the protocol (rtsp) isn't associated with any program.
```

It seems there is not possible to add a new protocol in Tools->Options->Applications dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RTSP is a protocol. This [mozillaZine article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Register_protocol) notes two ways of registering it :

**Updating about:config**

1. Type about:config into the Location Bar (address bar) and press Enter.
2. Right-click -> New -> Boolean -> Name: network.protocol-handler.expose.rtsp.
   Set its value to false .
3. Next time you click a link of protocol-type rtsp you will be asked which application to open it with. Enter `C:\Program Files\VideoLan\VLC\vlc.exe` (or whatever it is).

**Registry editing**

Make a rtsp.reg file and add the following:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\rtsp]
@="Real Time Streaming Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\rtsp\shell]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\rtsp\shell\open]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\rtsp\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\VideoLan\\VLC\\vlc.exe\" \"%1\""
```

Double click and add to registry.

Make sure the VLC Firefox plugins npvlc.dll and vlcintf.xpt are installed in Firefox plugin folder.

Comment: It does not help me on Firefox 12...

Answer (score 1):

1.Configuring Firefox for Streaming Media (Real Player/VLC)

You must install RealPlayer/VLC to open urls with the RTSP protocol (rtsp://) .
Streaming media often uses the RTSP protocol (as evidenced by the link itself, rtsp://address). Firefox does not know how to handle this protocol natively. This can result in the error RTSP is not a registered protocol when you try to access streaming media on the web.
There are several ways to correct the error. We recommend adjusting the Firefox configuration settings by adding an entry for the RTSP protocol:
Open Firefox, and type about:config in the URL bar.
Right click in the main window and select New and then Boolean.
Enter network.protocol-handler.expose.rtsp for the preference name and click OK.
Select false and click OK.
Now Click On the video link and browser says to choose a program to open the link, select real player or vlc player.
Firefox should now be able to correctly associate streaming media with RealPlayer/VLC. To test this, please Open m.youtube.com and click watch video.
Thanks